# Marginal download speed shown on Android, yet videos still play OK

Tags: android

I am testing watching videos and the Tor Browser client on Android often shows zero or very minimal download speed, even though the video plays fine. The Torbrowser still says that I am connected so everything should be fine but what bothers me is the zero or near zero download speed shown during the playback for much of the time, even if the video is in HD. What is happening? Does that mean that the problem is somewhat similar to the flash issue and the browser is connecting via the clearnet?
Tested on Android 13

Answer (score 0):

HD video requires very moderate download speed, so the player was connected through a fast hop path and the download speed has to be **just a bit** above the video bitrate speed to play it fine, that's why there's a feature called pre-buffering for a streamed content. It's not a problem you suspect